# Repeating elements of one array working, but failing for another when doing what appears to be the same exact thing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following HTML to repeat the elements of some arrays that are in a javascript object:

```
<div ng-repeat="info in pTab.infoData">
    <p>{{info}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="stats in pTab.modelData">  
    <p>{{stats}}</p>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant chunk of the javascript object with infoData and modelData:

[image: screenshot of object in chrome inspector]

As you can see, `infoData` and `modelData` are both at arrays, both at the same level, and both referenced the same ways in the HTML.

Why then, do the elements of `infoData` display on my page while the elements of `modelData`are nowhere to be found?

If you need more HTML, js, or a view of that full object, please let me know. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: just check are you using `stats` as variable in controller and view apart from this

Comment: @Satpal nope. I even switched around things like

`<div ng-repeat="info in pTab.modelData">
    <p>{{info}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="stats in pTab.infoData">  
    <p>{{stats}}</p>
</div>`




and got the same result